# Websphere fails to start : java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: CWWAR0015E: La création de JAXBContext a échoué

Tags: java, jaxb, websphere, websphere-8, ibm-rad

On a fresh installation of RAD 9.6.1 and Websphere 8.5.5.14 I have an error in the console, during WAS startup and I cannot access the Administrative Console.

```
[27/08/18 11:59:15:759 CEST] 00000001 JAXWSEndpoint E   CWWAR0015E: La création de JAXBContext a échoué.
[27/08/18 11:59:15:775 CEST] 00000001 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: Incident FFDC émis sur C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer8.5\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_62264962_18.08.27_11.59.15.7757098867834308933073.txt null 484
[27/08/18 11:59:15:791 CEST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Erreur de création du composant
[27/08/18 11:59:15:775 CEST] 00000001 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: Incident FFDC émis sur C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer8.5\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_62264962_18.08.27_11.59.15.7757098867834308933073.txt null 484
[27/08/18 11:59:15:791 CEST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Erreur de création du composant com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.jaxws.component.WSAddressingComponentImpl@831156d8
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: CWWAR0015E: La création de JAXBContext a échoué.
```

Error following:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: CWWAR0015E: La création de JAXBContext a échoué.
    at com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.jaxws21.factory.impl.JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.<init>(JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.jaxws.urimap.EndpointMappingListener.initialize(EndpointMappingListener.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.jaxws.urimap.EndpointMappingListener.<init>(EndpointMappingListener.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.jaxws.component.WSAddressingComponentImpl.start(WSAddressingComponentImpl.java:140)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:700)
    at com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.jaxws21.factory.impl.JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.<init>(JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.java:81)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl.createFallbackContext(JAXBContextImpl.java:462)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:220)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:262)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:249)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:456)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.jaxws21.factory.impl.JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl$1.run(JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.wsaddressing.jaxws21.factory.impl.JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl$1.run(JAXWSEndpointReferenceFactoryImpl.java:82)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:696)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl.createFallbackContext1(JAXBContextImpl.java:518)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl.access$100(JAXBContextImpl.java:71)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl$4.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl$4.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:504)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:696)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl.createFallbackContext0(JAXBContextImpl.java:504)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl.createFallbackContext(JAXBContextImpl.java:455)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:96)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:63)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:128)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:162)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:92)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:452)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:300)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1158)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE006 attribut StackMap/StackMapTable non valide; classe=java/awt/Component, méthode=addNotify()V, pc=446
Exception Details:
  Location:
    java/awt/Component.addNotify()V @446: JBastore
  Reason:
    Invalid stackmap specification
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [27, 443] => handler: 446
    bci [446, 450] => handler: 446
```

Anyone has an idea of what is happening? I did not know how to solve this, and I did not found helping information during my search. Thank you!

Comment: usually when I see `NoClassDefFoundError` for `RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl` it means that javax.activation APIs aren't available on the classpath (normally they come from the JDK though)

Comment: I already looked at this point, the `RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl` class is present on the JDK that is used by the Websphere process. The error is flagged `(initialization failure)` and there is this `ClassFormatError` error just after that I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working, I had a system environment `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` with the value :

```
-agentpath:"C:\WINDOWS\system32\Aternity\Java\JavaHookLoader.dll"="C:\ProgramData\Aternity\hooks
```

I overwrite the value to  (single space blank value) and it is working after restarting RAD and Websphere. No idea of the details,  this value was set by the software Aternity I suppose.